# Spring Boot - Kafka Consumer in Cloud Foundry

Tags: java, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I would like to run a Kafka Consumer instance developed using Spring Boot in Cloud Foundry. Is there a way to deploy an app without listening on any port (80 or 443)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cf push app --no-route --u process` to push your app and not have a route for it generated.
The `-u` flag ensures that the health checker determines whether the app started successfully by checking the process is alive, as opposed to whether it's listening to the port.

On old CF releases and cf CLI's you may find `process` is not supported. In that case, use `none` instead of `process`. (`none` was deprecated in favor of the more meaningful `process`, but they're just aliases and do exactly the same thing.)